# Can't provision SSL certificate for my subdomain

Tags: ssl-certificate

## Are only specific TLD's available for SSL certification?

I'm trying to provision an SSL certificate for my subdomain, (I own the root domain but can't afford a wildcard SSL yet) but I can't find an SSL provider who has it as an available option. Even the registrar that sold me the domain and an SSL certificate don't seem to support it...

the subdomain in question is [be.different.democrat](http://be.different.democrat)

123-Reg the domain registrar I purchased it from don't allow it in the "Assign SSL - Wizard"

I tried to get a free SSL from Start-SSL, but they have a dropdown list of available TLD's which doesn't include `.democrat` - I tried hacking about the HTML on the registration form to allow me to submit `.democrat` as a form value and it failed verification.

Any suggestions, or at least a definitive answer as to why I'm unable to provision an SSL certificate for the subdomain.

Comment: It's a [valid TLD](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) so the problem is with the SSL certificate issuer. Use another company.

Comment: I've tried 2 already, 1 purchased which I'll be getting refunded asap and one free. Got any suggestions as to somewhere I could purchase one from with some sort of guarantee that they'll support the TLD ?

Comment: Contact 123-reg's support only they can help you.

Comment: There is nothing we can do to help the OP.

Comment: I don't understand why somebody want this question closed as "asking for product recommendation". It is not asking which TLD to use or which CA to use. It is asking if there are any reasons why domains under some TLDs cannot get a certificate at all. That is a valid question, and a few answers were given already.

Comment: The reason is "because no CA supports it". It's not a technical question, it's a shopping/policy one.

Comment: It is supported by at least 1 CA - the above comment is misleading/incorrect

Comment: @JennyD I think you are mistaken. It is not a policy question. I see the the question as asking if the restriction is due to technical or policy reasons. And *that* is a technical question. That said, if there was a globally accepted policy, I don't see how questions about that policy would be off-topic. The answer to the question does naturally lead to follow-up questions, which would be off-topic. But that doesn't make the original question off-topic.

Comment: How can anyone other than the SSL provider know whether their decision to not offer certificates for a TLD is due to their own technical reasons or their own policy reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to provision a valid SSL certificate for free for 90 days from [instantssl](http://www.instantssl.com/).

Answer (score 2):

As the live-start of the .democrat TLD was 4 days ago (May, 21st 2014), it might take a moment until the providers support it.

Try godaddy.com, as they sell domains + ssl certificates, and may already support it.
(Or any other provider which sells .democrat and also SSL certificates, as I expect them to launch that simultaneously)

Comment: thanks, as my registrar sold me .democrat I assumed they'd support it I won't be investing in godaddy just incase they don't and I can't see any information confirming they do prior to the checkout

Comment: then ask them :)